# How do you lower the point at where Measurement changes suffix?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When you use [Measurement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement), depending on the value given and the format, it will switch from a smaller suffix to a large suffix. Example: ft -> mi or m -> km.

Here it seems the suffix switches at 0.50 miles. I'm wondering if the "switch" point can be changed either higher or lower. It also seems the unit type doesn't make a difference.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(Measurement(value: 805, unit: UnitLength.meters)
                    .formatted(
                        .measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)
                    )
            )
            
            Text(Measurement(value: 804, unit: UnitLength.meters)
                    .formatted(
                        .measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)
                    )
            )
            
            Text(Measurement(value: 0.5, unit: UnitLength.miles)
                    .formatted(
                        .measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)
                    )
            )
            
            Text(Measurement(value: 0.499, unit: UnitLength.miles)
                    .formatted(
                        .measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .road)
                    )
            )
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't. You can disable the `naturalScale` and handle it yourself. Usually Apple is pretty good with it, but some things don't make sense, or don't make sense in the particular context in which you are using it.

Comment: They use it in their workout app when you're running/walking. It switches from feet to 0.1 mi.

Comment: I understand. I have an app where things are always dealt with in inches or feet, and the formatter wants to use feet at 12 inches, or yards at 3 feet.